# Conflict between letter-spacing and text-align:center?

Tags: html, css

Using `letter-spacing` seems to really screw with `text-align`: http://jsfiddle.net/NFAzv/

Googling hasn't turned anything up. Am I missing something here?

EDIT #1: Here's what I'm getting (Firefox 3.6.8 and Chrome 12.0.742.91 on Vista): *link removed due to link limits for newbies (it can be found in the comments)* (notice how the centers do not line up at all)

EDIT #2: Here's IE9, with a centered vertical line to show what's wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0J0n.png

EDIT #3: I have a confirmation in the comments below that the problem shows up for Chrome 10 on Windows 7. At least I'm not the only one going crazy.

Comment: what browser are you using? Looks as expected in chrome on mac osx

Comment: Works fine for me, Chrome 10 on Windows 7

Comment: Works for me, Chrome 12 on Linux.

Comment: What's the problem? Fine here on FF4 Win7 too.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting (Firefox 3.6.8 and Chrome 12.0.742.91 on Vista): http://i.imgur.com/oGKY2.png

Comment: @Andrew, @Pekka: Does your screen resemble the above screenshot, or do the centers of the words line up?

Comment: IE9, IE8 and IE7 center just fine, though IE7 results in smaller text.

Comment: @NGLN: I have a screenshot of IE9. It doesn't center properly.

Comment: You're right: It doesn't center properly in Chrome 10 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Dave2: Try that again with all text selected... ;-)

Comment: @NGLN: OK, here it is with the text selected: http://i.imgur.com/Oya4F.png. As you can see, it's still not centered.

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo: Can I perhaps have a screenshot and your browser information? That would be helpful to figuring out what's going on.

Comment: I'm using IE 8.0.7600 - windows seven, and I cannot upload the photo. I'm sorry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that all the browser have converged on a letter-spacing implementation that is plainly at odds with what css3 says should happen.

In particular see Example XV at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#letter-spacing0

Browsers simply don't do this. IE has even changed its behaviour recently (IE9, I think) to be more like the other browsers, and less like the CSS3 spec as it's currently written.

The CSS3 spec in question is still at working draft status, so presumably at some point it will be changed to match what the browsers do.

You may be able to rebalance the lines by adding a padding-left value to match the letter-spacing but that may not always be possible.

Comment: I see. So all the browsers are so stupid that CSS will (hopefully in the future) make itself stupid as well, so that the two forms of stupidity will cancel each other out?

Comment: But hold on: if all the browsers get this wrong, then what explains all the "works for me" comments above?

Comment: I guess that the “works for me” comments do refer to situations where the font size is small with many letters in one line. Then it is really a pixel or two problem. But if you have (as I observed in many cases) let’s say 5 letters and a big font size then the de-centering is no longer a joke. As I said below it seems that the browsers add the letter spacing also to the last letter. A regular layout program (like InDesign or whatever) wouldn’t do that! Setting a padding-left to half value of spacing can help.

Answer (score 11):

Since the problem isn't really described I assume that the text isn't centered perfectly..

You can use `text-indent` at half the size of the letter spacing to correct this..

```
.centered {
  letter-spacing:12px;
  text-indent:6px;
}
```

Only tested on Chrome OSX though..

Comment: Such an elegant solution. Although, it seems that chrome (Ubuntu, not chromium) adds the spacing after the letter (e.g. 12px space after a letter is displayed), so I guess I should text-indent the same amount rather than half the size for chrome. Haven't tested on other OS/browsers... just yet.

Comment: Firefox on Windows does the same. I'm fairly certain letter-spacing simply just adds it on the right of the letter in most browsers.

Answer (score 9):

It seems to work, but your requirement for this pixel perfectness does not comply with the default working of `letter-spacing`. If you highlight the text, you will see that it does center.

You could use the following workaround: [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/NFAzv/6/)

```
<div style="text-align: center;">           
  <div style="font-size: 130%; letter-spacing: 0.6em; padding-left: 0.6em;">THIS</div>
  <div style="font-size: 350%; letter-spacing: 0.4em; padding-left: 0.4em;">ILLUSTRATES</div>            
  <div style="font-size: 130%; letter-spacing: 0.4em; padding-left: 0.4em;">THE</div>
  <div style="font-size: 200%; letter-spacing: 0.1em; padding-left: 0.1em;">PROBLEM</div>           
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but are you saying that CSS is so stupid that it doesn't know how to center words with letter spacing?

Answer (score 5):

I have seen similar problem with links underline:last letter's width includes the letter-spacing value.
So apply `letter-spacing:0;` for the last letters should resolve the issue.
It's ugly but it works

```
...
<div style="font-size: 350%; letter-spacing: 0.4em;">
    ILLUSTRATE<span style="letter-spacing:0;">S</span>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Wow, that's horrible. Thanks, but surely CSS isn't that stupid, is it?

Comment: See Alohci's link, CSS isn't stupid, but maybe its implementation ^^

Comment: Ugly hack but it fixes the issue.

Comment: For my eyes (and in my case) it in fact seems that browsers add a letter spacing also to the last letter what is not done by a regular font setting program here. So if the letter spacing increases the wrong centering error gets bigger. Good point Mat! Your solution (for my eyes) is the correct solution. However one decides to programmatically introduce this into code. (if a markUp style i.g. is not possible)

Comment: I found the (hacky) solution in the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441742/change-last-letter-color helpful to do this.

Answer (score 0):

add 50% of the font size as text indent like this

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="font-size: 130%; letter-spacing: 0.6em;text-indent:0.3em">THIS</div>
        <div style="font-size: 350%; letter-spacing: 0.4em;text-indent:0.2em">ILLUSTRATES</div>
        <div style="font-size: 130%; letter-spacing: 0.4em;text-indent:0.2em">THE</div>
        <div style="font-size: 200%; letter-spacing: 0.1em;text-indent:0.05em">PROBLEM</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this wasn't the exact question here, I had an issue that the starting left point of the text was too far to the right:

I had an issue that my text wasn't centered horisontally any longer after letter-spacing was applied but it was due to that I had restricted the texts container in width, so it was overflowing it's container.. worth to look into.. it may seem stupid but it's an easy misstake actually.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to this, but just in case my solution helps anyone.

This is an example simple button set up:

```
<button><a href="">Enter</a></button>
```

In my stylesheet:

```
button {
    color: #f5ebe0;
    border-color: #f5ebe0;
    background-color: #00000000;

    text-indent: 2rem;

    width: 33%;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2rem;
}
```

It seems that letter-spacing does indeed only add spacing either to the right, or only in between the letters. This being the case, (when using letter-spacing) I recommend using an anchor tag with in the button and applying your letter-spacing amount to the text inside the anchor, and then apply the SAME amount of text-indent inside your button.

Comment: Make sure to keep `<button>`-elements for buttons and `<a>`-elements for links only, for improved accessibility

Comment: Absolutely. I actually did this because I was having an issue with one of my navigation buttons wrapping text, so I first try to span the text inside of a button to have better manipulation but ended up using anchors. Would you mind recommending a better strategy for dealing with that? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: By the button text of "Enter" it seems like this would be better suited semantically as an `<a>` element. `Button` elements are meant for on-page interactivity like submitting a form or opening a dialog box, which is why they do not have an `href` attribute. If you need a link for navigation between pages then you should be using an `<a>` element, which you can then style like a button.