# Change last letter color

Tags: html, css

Example code:

```
<p class="test">string</p>
```

I want to change the color on the last letter, in this case "g", but I need solution with css, I don't need a javascript solution.

I display the string letter by letter and i cant use static solution.

Comment: <p class='test'>strin<span style='color:red;'>g</span></p>

Comment: I display the string letter by letter and i cant use this static solution.

Comment: Then you need to update your example with more code. "display the string letter by letter" doesn't really help, and indicates that you've got some more code behind the scenes that could be useful.

Comment: There's no CSS-only solution that doesn't involve wrapping the last letter in a tag that can be matched by a selector. There's no ::last-letter analog of the ::first-letter pseudo-element.

Comment: In what way do you "display the string letter by letter"? If you're looping through the characters in a string (variable) you can certainly tell when you're at the last letter and wrap it in a `<span class="lastletter">` whether doing so on the server side or client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to apply different styles to different letters in word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201699/is-it-possible-to-apply-different-styles-to-different-letters-in-word)

Comment: @Koki See my updated answer, but why did you not want a javascript-based solution? Your fiddle has quite a bit of js in it already.

Comment: @David thanks for the solution, it's very helpful. I think that there is a css solution like 'first-letter', so that's why I want something more simple, but this is also very helpful.

Comment: I've come up with a working CSS-only solution. It's not pretty though, though. See my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without using javascript, your only option is:

```
<p class="test">strin<span class="other-color">g</span></p>
```

*Edit for your fiddle link*:

I'm not really sure why you said you didn't need a javascript solution, since you have quite a bit of it already. Regardless, in this example, you need to make only a couple small changes. Change line 10 from

```
elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
```

to

```
if ( current == contentArray.length-1 ) {
    elem.html(elem.html() + "<span style='color:red'>"+contentArray[current++]+"</span>");
} else {
    elem.html(elem.html() + contentArray[current++]);
}
```

Note that it's important to use `.html()` instead of `.text()` now, since there's actually HTML markup being inserted.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QTUsb/2/

Comment: That’s the only option even when using JavaScript, in the sense that JavaScript would create the equivalent of this markup in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 211):

Everyone says it can't be done. I'm here to prove otherwise.

Yes, it **can** be done.

Okay, so it's a horrible hack, but it can be done.

We need to use two CSS features:

- Firstly, CSS provides the ability to change the direction of the flow of the text. This is typically used for scripts like Arabic or Hebrew, but it actually works for any text. If we use it for English text, the letters are displayed in reverse order to how the appear in the markup. So to get the text to show as the word "String" on a reversed element, we would have to have markup that reads "gnirtS".
- Secondly, CSS has the `::first-letter` pseudo-element selector, which selects the first letter in the text. (other answers already established that this is available, but there's no equivalent `::last-letter` selector)

Now, if we combine the `::first-letter` with the reversed text, we can select the first letter of "gnirtS", but it'll look like we're selecting the last letter of "String".

So our CSS looks like this:

```
div {
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
    direction:rtl;
}

div::first-letter {
    color: blue;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div>gnirtS</div>
```

Yes, this does work -- you can see the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gFcA9/

But as I say, it is a bit hacky. And who wants to spend their time writing everything backwards? Not really a practical solution, but it does answer the question.

Comment: Definitely +1 for sheer bloody minded hackiness. My kind of answer!

Comment: I do not understand, though, what the `unicode-bidi:bidi-override;` statement is doing. Could you explain this or post a link describing what this is doing and why your using it here?

Comment: @WebWanderer: It handles how the reversed text is rendered. It's been long enough since I wrote this that I don't really remember the details, so my suggestion is to work it out the way I did; ie read [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi), and also experiment with the jsfiddle example by trying it without the property, and with other values. Its the best way of learning. You may also find it's the kind of thing that has cross-browser implications; that's always something to watch out for, especially when doing something slightly hacky.

Comment: plus one for sheer creativity. Now, how would you use this to style the first *and* last letter?

Comment: @SidPen: No, if anything, the fact that this is a hack (and it acknowledges itself as such) means it *shouldn't* be the accepted answer. You almost certainly shouldn't be using it unless you're trying to prove a point, and I hope the OP doesn't either unless they want to get themselves into trouble. This is probably one of the few times I'm glad the OP isn't around to switch accepted answers anymore.

Comment: @chharvey: Given the very nature of this hack I don't think that is possible unless you duplicate parts of the code somehow.

Comment: The Vicar of Nibbleswicke would love it!

Answer (score 55):

Use `::after` pseudo-element combined with [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function:

```
p::after {
    content: attr(data-end) ;
    color: red ;
}
<p data-end="g">Strin</p>
```

```css
p::after {
  content: attr(data-end) ;
  color: red ;
}
```

```html
<p data-end="g">Strin</p>
```

Comment: +1 Another great approach using data attributes! Thanks for this as it is more appropriate when using dynamic view generation handling. I might make the switch to this! Thanks @supersharp

Comment: aaah this way is perfect but always a problem 
the css will deal with the `data-end` as a new element which will ruin display flex

Answer (score 29):

Another solution is to use `::after`

```
.test::after{
    content: "g";
    color: yellow;
}
<p class="test">strin</p>
```

This solution allows to change the color of all characters not only letters like the answer from Spudley that uses `::first-letter`. See `::first-letter` [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-letter) for more information. `::first-letter` applies only on letters it ignores punctuation symbols.

Moreover if you want to color more than the last character you can :

```
.test::after{
     content: "ing";
     color: yellow;
}
<p class="test">str</p>
```

For more information on ::after check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp).

Comment: I upvoted because, well, I'm a css lover, and I think this is actually an elegant and smart solution to make the last letter different than the others.

I would just love to be able to actually "copy" this letter, but since `:after` elements are not selectable, we can't do much.

Comment: It sadly doesn't on placeholders (at least with Firefox) but that's the way to go.

Comment: +1 here for reminding me that I could solve my required fields asteriks being parsed through my laravel engine not supporting inline markup. Thanks @Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 12):

It could be achieved using only CSS and an `::after` pseudo-element without any changes in HTML:

```css
.test {
  font-size: 16pt;
  position: relative;
}
.test::after {
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  content: 'g';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<p class="test">string</p>
```

Comment: I think that this is the best solution in most cases. No need to write text backwards, add attributes or use js.

Answer (score 1):

In what way do you "display the string letter by letter"? If you're looping through the characters in a string (variable) you can certainly tell when you're at the last letter and wrap it in a  whether doing so on the server side or client side.

Looking at the fiddles attached to [another of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448819/) ...

If this is what you're talking about, you might have to set the `.innerHTML` of the element instead of the `element.text()`

From the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/SLKEn/ you would change it to something like this

```
if(current < contentArray.length) {
    elem.html(
            elem.html() +
              (current == contentArray.length-1 ?
               '<span class="lastchar">' + contentArray[current++] + '</span>' :
               contentArray[current++])
             );
        }
```

along with CSS `span.lastchar { color: red; }`

---

Update: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLKEn/5/) based on your other question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str=$("span").text();
  strArr=str.split("");
  for(var key=0;key<=strArr.length-1;key++) {
    if(key==strArr.length-1) {
      var newEle="<span id='lastElement'>"+strArr[key]+"</div>";
      strArr[key]=newEle;
    }
  }
  var newtext=strArr.join("");
  $("span").html(newtext);  
});
```

```css
  
span#lastElement {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont have the ability to comment on an answer thread but i wanted to point out an error in an [answer provided by Marc_Alx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604162/1668200) that otherwise works wonderfully. that solution worked for me only after adding a semi-colon behind the `content` property... so it looks like `content:"ing";`

```
.test::after{
  content:"ing";
  color:yellow;
}
<p class="test">str</p>
```