# How can I change the color of the last letter in an element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

How can I change color of a last letter to red using CSS?

```
<asp:Label ID="QuestionText" runat="server" CssClass="asterisk"></asp:Label>

.asterisk:after
{
    color: Red;
    content: " *";
}
```

The problem is Questions are coming from the database. So I can really make changes to the text itself, please see below:

Below is the text from the database:
Question:

Sample Text

Sample Text

Sample Text

Comment: *Please note:* you must include your try and effort to solve the issue.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441742/change-last-letter-color

Comment: I don't know about you, but it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/906r29zt/1/

Comment: Hi @chdltest, I've got multiple list as below:
'<ul>
    <li id="sample-text">I am not happy</li>
    <li id="sample-text">I am not happy</li><li>I am not happy</li><li>I am not happy</li>' 

So I need to put ! at the end.
</ul>

Comment: Nope, still don't know what you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/906r29zt/2/

Comment: @WickedVigour We're trying to help you, but you need to show your *full* code for us to do so.

Comment: @WickedVigour no need to put CSS in the title, trust the tagging system

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do anymore. I don't know what your HTML is, I don't know what this form you speak of is, I don't know if you're talking about the last letter of your paragraph or the last letter of each list item. **PS, it would help if your code reflects your example and you clearly state what you want instead of giving us code that isn't related to your example.**

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain it properly, but its fixed with the below answer.
Thanks for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the last-child property of the specific element, or the nth-child option.