# Change a single placeholder character color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway to get this script to work if its even possible, I want to add a red (*) to the end of specific placeholders I tried the CSS :after pseudo which works really well in chrome. But I need it cross browser.

I have some java script that replaces any (*) with a red(*) but with it being in a place holder it displays the tags.

```
<head>
#inputFormBorder ::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {color:red;content:"*";}
#inputFormBorder ::-moz-placeholder:after {color:red;content:"*";}
#inputFormBorder :-ms-input-placeholder:after {color:red;content:"*";}

#inputFormBorder0 ::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {content:"";}
#inputFormBorder0 ::-moz-placeholder:after {content:"";}
#inputFormBorder0 :-ms-input-placeholder:after {content:"";}

input {width:300px;}
</head>
<body>
<h4>this only works in chrome</h4>
<div id="inputFormBorder">
    <input name="UserName" type="text" id="UserName" placeholder="User Name or Email">
   <div>

       <br><br>

<h4>cross browser?</h4>
<div id="inputFormBorder0">
    <input name="UserName" type="text" id="UserName" placeholder="User Name or Email*">
   <div>

  <br><br>

<div id="inputFormBorder">
    js turned this red *
   <div>

<script>
$('#inputFormBorder0').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(\*)/g, '<span style="color: red;">*</span>'));
});
</script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zo16ruxd/15/

this jsfiddle should explain better.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible just yet. But take a look at this, it might be a solution you could use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15443126/663668

Comment: You are trying to iterate on 1 jQuery element (selector is looking for an ID). `$('#inputFormBorder0').each(function ()`. I think the best approach is to add a class, example: "required" to all input fileds that need a red *. After, iterate through them and `append('<span style="color: red;">*</span>')`

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/zo16ruxd/17/
if yes, why not use `<span>`?