# Setup background images to open/close around paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to setup a design where background images "open/close" around a paragraph. I tried setting it up so that two divs were added to the paragraph's container, and them set them up with `position:absolute` and all that jazz, but the "closing" image will always stick to the far right of the container instead of sticking the the last word of the paragraph.

Is it possible to set this up without javascript?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to setup:

[image: Open/close paragraph design]

Comment: Does the closing be near to the last letter? I am not sure if there's a `:last-letter` selector, LoL. You may require JavaScript for this.

Comment: Check this out: [Change last letter color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441742/change-last-letter-color).

Comment: Take a look at Lettering.js and this: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: @Roope Without JavaScript. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Aight, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using `:before` and `:after`. Check out the below snippet:

```css
p:before, p:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 0;
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Block-quote.svg/60px-VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Block-quote.svg.png") -28px -25px;
}

p:before {
  left: 10px;
  background-position: -3px -5px;
}

p {
  text-indent: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni labore explicabo molestias, libero similique veniam unde, cum quas neque architecto, consectetur, pariatur porro ex et dolorem voluptatibus repellat! Numquam, voluptate!</p>
```

Not even buggy. Works nice. Check.

Comment: Works great, had to make a few modifications to your example to setup the positioning. Hadn't thought of using `:before` and `:after`

Comment: @Chaosxmk Yes, as I said before, it might be buggy, you need to fix it up. `:)`