# How to give the color to * without using span Tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I am doing working with WordPress and using event Plus plugin that plugin

is using the form. some field are predefined and some field we can create using

customize functionality.My requirement is I want to show required field * color

red.And I can't use the span tag because it is creating the problem with form

validation message. I just want * should be show in red color. How can I use

CSS for that.

the form is below:-

```html
<form name="regform" class="evrplus_regform" method="post" action="https://manresa-sj.com/evrplus_registration/?" onsubmit="mySubmit.disabled = true;
       return validateForm(this)">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="fname">First Name*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="lname">Last Name*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="email">Email Address*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4138">Name and Date of Retreat*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" class="r" id="TEXT_4138" name="TEXT_4138" size="40" title="Name and Date of Retreat*" value="" disabled="disabled"></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4139">Is this is your first retreat there*</label>
      <span class="radio"><input id="SINGLE_4139_0" class="r" name="SINGLE_4139" title="Is t" type="radio" value="Yes"> Yes</span><span class="radio"><input id="SINGLE_4139_1" class="r" name="SINGLE_4139" title="Is t" type="radio" value="No"> No</span> 
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4140">Title: Mr, Mrs, Ms….</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4140" name="TEXT_4140" size="40" title="Title: Mr, Mrs, Ms...." value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4141">Nickname</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4141" name="TEXT_4141" size="40" title="Nickname" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4142">Suffix: MD, Sr….</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4142" name="TEXT_4142" size="40" title="Suffix: MD, Sr...." value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4143">Birthday</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4143" name="TEXT_4143" size="40" title="Birthday" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4144">Profession</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4144" name="TEXT_4144" size="40" title="Profession" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4145">Spouse’s Name</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4145" name="TEXT_4145" size="40" title="Spouse's Name" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4146">Parish Name</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4146" name="TEXT_4146" size="40" title="Parish Name" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4147">Home Phone*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" class="r" id="TEXT_4147" name="TEXT_4147" size="40" title="Home Phone*" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4148">Mobile Phone</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4148" name="TEXT_4148" size="40" title="Mobile Phone" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4149">Business Phone</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4149" name="TEXT_4149" size="40" title="Business Phone" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4150">Contact in case of Emergency</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4150" name="TEXT_4150" size="40" title="Contact in case of Emergency" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4151">Relationship to you</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="TEXT_4151" name="TEXT_4151" size="40" title="Relationship to you" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4152">Address*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" class="r" id="TEXT_4152" name="TEXT_4152" size="40" title="Address*" value=""></span>
    </li>
    <li title="">
      <label for="question-4153">City*</label>
      <span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" class="r" id="TEXT_4153" name="TEXT_4153" size="40" title="City*" value=""></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I found a duplicate question with better hack answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441742/change-last-letter-color

Comment: Using css, it cannot be done, since there is no `:last-letter` pseudo selector (there is `:first-letter` but that's of no use to you). Also the rtl hack is only good if you have written the labels backwards, which is really bad hack (If you can change the direction of the letters, you can add a `<span>` around the * as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jQuery`:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").each(function(){
    var labelValue = $(this).text();
    if(labelValue.includes("*")){
        $(this).addClass("required");
      $(this).text(labelValue.replace("*",""));
    }
  });
});
```

and `css`:

```
.evrplus_regform label.required:after{
  content:"*";
  color:red;
}
```

Try it yourself [here](https://jsfiddle.net/09dttd7u/2/).

## Pure css way:

Just add `required` class to your required label and use `css` above.

```
<label for="fname" class="required">First Name</label>
```

Comment: I just only  want * should be  red not full label

Comment: there is no way to add red color only for `*` without add any tag.

Comment: I have updated my answer and it's now match your requirement

Comment: There is no pure CSS way of doing this, and answer above can be the best solution.

Comment: Just add required class to your required label and use css above.

Comment: @JeradRutnam thanks but I found a pure css way to do this

Comment: @JaredChu, agreed just need to remove "*" and add "required" class. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
    <style>
    label[for="fname"]:after, label[for="lname"]:after, label[for="email"]:after  { 
content: "* "; color:red;
 }
    </style>
```

Comment: WHY WASNT THIS THE ACCEPTED ANSWER, ITS PURE CSS!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <label for="fname">First Name<font color=red>*</font></label>
```

Try This