# Changing the color of the last character of a word with a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how can I change the color of the last character of a word in a `<p>` tag with a Javascript loop. In the example below, I want to change the color of the "n" in the word "John", the "s" in "Jacques", the "r" in "Peter", etc.

```
<section>
   <h1>Name</h1>

   <p>John</p>
   <p>Jacques</p>
   <p>Peter</p>
   <p>Robert</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('#pColors p')
  .forEach(p => {
    const len = p.innerText.length - 1
    p.innerHTML = `${p.innerText.slice(0, len)} <span class="red">${p.innerText[len]}</span>`
  })
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<section id="pColors">
   <h1>Name</h1>

   <p>John</p>
   <p>Jacques</p>
   <p>Peter</p>
   <p>Robert</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(el => {
  const prefix = el.innerText.substr(0, el.innerText.length - 1);
  const suffix = el.innerText.substr(el.innerText.length - 1);
  el.innerHTML = `${prefix}<span class="colored">${suffix}</span>`;
})
```

Using `document.querySelectorAll` we select all of the `<p>` tags on the page. We then loop over the `NodeList` using `NodeList#forEach`. For each iteration we pick out all of the characters except the last, and then pick out the last character. Finally we reconstruct the content of the element using `innerHTML` and use a template string to wrap the single character in a `<span>`.

This code assumes you have CSS that looks something like this:

```css
.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(el => {
  const prefix = el.innerText.substr(0, el.innerText.length - 1);
  const suffix = el.innerText.substr(el.innerText.length - 1);
  el.innerHTML = `${prefix}<span class="colored">${suffix}</span>`;
})
```

```css
.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <h1>Name</h1>

   <p>John</p>
   <p>Jacques</p>
   <p>Peter</p>
   <p>Robert</p>
</section>
```

Comment: With real world users, without a transpiler (which I'm guessing the OP does not use), `forEach` is not always available in the `NodeList` prototype. Neither are template literals. IE 11 is sadly still in use...

Comment: This will destroy any elements that might reside inside the paragraph. Consider working on textNodes or using innerHTML all the way instead.

Comment: @connexo Certainly. I was simply going off the provided code example.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let list = ['John', 'Jacques', 'Peter', 'Robert'];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  let name = list[i];
  document.getElementById("list-container").innerHTML += `<p> ${name.substr(0, name.length - 1)}<span style="color: red">${name.charAt(name.length - 1)}<span><p>`
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container"></div>
```

Comment: Explanations are nice. So a working snippets. I made one for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS too.

```css
p::after {
  content: attr(data-end) ;
  color: red ;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <h1>Name</h1>

   <p data-end="n">Joh</p>
   <p data-end="s">Jacque</p>
   <p data-end="r">Pete</p>
   <p data-end="t">Rober</p>
</section>
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31038089/10971575

Comment: This is a bad solution for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Insteresting solution